# numpy, mapping one array to parts of another

Tags: python, numpy

lets say i have one array

```
    a = numpy.arange(8*6*3).reshape((8, 6, 3))
    #and another:
    l = numpy.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,1]]) #an array of indexes to array "a"
    #and yet another:
    b = numpy.array([[0,0,5],[0,1,0],[1,1,3]])
```

where "l" and "b" are of equal length,
and i want to say

```
    a[l] = b
```

such that a[0][0] becomes [0,0,5], a[0][1] becomes [0,1,0] etc.

it seems to work fine when ive got one-dimensional arrays, but it gives me the error

```
    ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape
```

when i try it with a 3-dimensional array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(8*6*3).reshape((8, 6, 3))
l = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,1]]) #an array of indexes to array "a"
b = np.array([[0,0,5],[0,1,0],[1,1,3]])

a[tuple(l.T)] = b
print(a[0,0])
# [0 0 5]

print(a[0,1])
# [0 1 0]

print(a[1,1])
# [1 1 3]
```

[Anne Archibald says](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2010-September/052549.html),

> When you are supplying arrays in all index slots, what you get back
>   has the same shape as the arrays you put in; so if you supply
>   one-dimensional lists, like
>
> A[[1,2,3],[1,4,5],[7,6,2]]
>
> what you get is
>
> [A[1,1,7], A[2,4,6], A[3,5,2]]

When you compare that with your example, you see that

`a[l] = b` tells NumPy to set

```
a[0,0,1] = [0,0,5]
a[0,1,1] = [0,1,0]
```

and leaves the third element of `b` unassigned. This is why you get the error

```
ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape
```

The solution is to transpose the array `l` into the correct shape:

```
In [50]: tuple(l.T)
Out[50]: (array([0, 0, 1]), array([0, 1, 1]))
```

(You could also use `zip(*l)`, but `tuple(l.T)` is a bit quicker.)

Comment: with "a[zip(*l)]" i get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    a[zip(*l)] = b
IndexError: index must be either an int or a sequence

Answer (score 0):

Or with your same arrays you can use

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    a[l[i][0]][l[i][1]]=b[i]
```